# I2C via MCU works with FLAG_WRITE_READ but not FLAG_READ

Tags: microcontroller, i2c, c, rtc

I'm reading the date from an [RTC](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/DS3231.pdf) via I2C using a [SiLabs MCU](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/368/efr32mg21-datasheet-1627395.pdf).  There are two different flag options, but only the 2nd one works.

I'm new to implementing I2C, what is happening on the wire that works for WRITE_READ but not just a bare READ?

**1. I2C_FLAG_READ - does NOT work**

```
#define I2C_FLAG_READ   0x0002
    
    Indicate plain read sequence: S+ADDR(R)+DATA0+P.

    S - Start
    ADDR(R) - Address with W/R bit set
    DATA0 - Data read into buffer with index 0
    P - Stop
```

**2. I2C_FLAG_WRITE_READ - DOES work**

```
#define I2C_FLAG_WRITE_READ   0x0004

Indicate combined write/read sequence: S+ADDR(W)+DATA0+Sr+ADDR(R)+DATA1+P.

    S - Start
    Sr - Repeated start
    ADDR(W) - Address with W/R bit cleared
    ADDR(R) - Address with W/R bit set
    DATAn - Data written from/read into buffer with index n
    P - Stop
```

Comment: _what is happening on the wire_ - do you have an oscilloscope?

Comment: I have an HP54610B scope, but not sure if it can capture and freeze the signals. Maybe there is a way?

Comment: Refer to the datasheet, Figure 5 on page 17. "Write-Read" is exactly how it's supposed to work. You 1st need to write the register pointer, then you read from that register. Once you've written the register pointer you can just do another read, and you'll get the value from the next register, but you can't just start with a read without first telling it where you want to read from.

Comment: @brhans, that is the answer.  Do single-value devices not need the register pointer so they can just be read without a write?

Comment: Define how it does not work? What do you do on I2C bus and how do you expect it to work?

Comment: @KJ7LNW I2C is a physical and data link level specification, memory serving. It doesn't specify whether or not a slave device carries an "address pointer concept," so far as I'm aware. This just means you need to read the slave device documentation with understanding. Sometimes, that comes faster. Sometimes, slower. But usually after re-reading it a few times things start to sink in. (My experience, anyway.) If you look at the read protocol, you'll see that there's no place for the word address pointer in the protocol. Which means it must come from some other communication.